# Dividir resulta sql em linhas através de delimitador

Tags: postgresql, select

Boa tarde pessoal.
To com uma dificuldade pra fazer um select em um DB postgres aqui.

Por algum motivo, o programador inventou de criar um campo aonde se, o usuario der entrada em duas notas ao mesmo tempo, o sistema grava no banco somente uma linha para aquele lançamento porém separando as duas notas por uma virgula no campo recn_numerodcto.

Portanto, se eu executar o select abaixo no banco,

```
 select  recn_data, recn_unid, recn_numerodcto from recnota
```

O resultado vai ser:

> recn_data | recn_unid | recn_numerodcto
>
> 25-09-2018 | 001 | 123, 321

Existe uma forma de eu quebrar esse resultado para gerar uma linha para cada nota? Ex:

> recn_data | recn_unid | recn_numerodcto
>
> 25-09-2018 | 001 | 123
>
> 25-09-2018 | 001 | 321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a combinação da função `string_to_array` com a função `unnest`.

`string_to_array`: converte a string informada no primeiro parâmetro em um `array` separando os elementos conforme o delimitador informado no segundo parâmetro.

`unnest`: Expande um array para um conjunto de `rows`.

```
select
    recn_data, 
    recn_unid, 
    unnest(string_to_array(recn_numerodcto,','))
from recnota
```

Adicionei alguns registros no banco de dados de exemplo:

```
insert into recnota (recn_data,recn_unid,recn_numerodcto)
values
    ('2018-09-25','001','123,321'),
    ('2018-09-26','001','1234,4321');
```

Executando o primeiro código irá retornar:

```
┌────────────┬───────────┬────────┐
│ recn_data  │ recn_unid │ unnest │
├────────────┼───────────┼────────┤
│ 2018-09-25 │ 001       │ 123    │
│ 2018-09-25 │ 001       │ 321    │
│ 2018-09-26 │ 001       │ 1234   │
│ 2018-09-26 │ 001       │ 4321   │
└────────────┴───────────┴────────┘
(4 registros)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Bom dia.
Deu muito certo com o "unnest".
Ajudou bastante. Obrigado